# How to support multiple screen sizes when using SQLite db with images?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know that I could use different dpi images from ldpi, mdpi and hdpi drawables but I'm using sqlite database populated with images. So how to use different dpi to support multiple screen sizes? Should I use 3 tables with different dpi's, and if so, how to trigger those table to be used on different screen?

Comment: you could use a single table with a density column, or several columns for several densities. The issue you'll be facing is handling default images when all sizes are not available/required

Comment: I do have 3 sizes for all images, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi. How to use that density column? Can you show me an example?

Comment: And more important how to retrieve those images depending on the screen of the phone running my app?

Comment: Why do you store images in the database? It's a wrong idea.

Comment: It's easier for me to complete my idea. What do you suggest?

Comment: just get the screen density and use it in your select clause.

Comment: But how to know which one to call? Can you give me some example in code, if you have some time?